# Angular default class errorHandler overrided handler method not catching up few error like 400 Bad request or 404 not found error

Tags: javascript, angular

I was trying to create a class which simply implements the angular own ErrorHandler class where i overrided method handler(error) function which catch all the errors occured .
However I observed like some error :-

> 400 bad Request

and

> 404 Not found

errors are not being caugth up by this method.How to catch these errors as well for loging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom HTTP interceptor for this. For example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()
    export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next
          .handle(req)
          .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              // do something with incoming error
              // (you can find error status under err.status)
            }
            return Observable.throw(err);
          });
      }
    }
```

To make it work add this to the main app module providers array:

`{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor, multi: true }`